# Poem coding scientific constants

Tags: mathematics, cipher, music, science

The following Vogon poem contains various mathematical, scientific and cosmological numbers. There are ten. Can you find them? Credit for partial solutions.

A BTAUJV BTA ALEJM AV EUMJM FAV EATR O

Answer (score 0):

A BTAUJV BTA ALEJM AV EUMJM FAV EATR O

> [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) OR [1](https://www.xkcd.com/1292/) : A B**TAU**JV BTA ALEJM AV EUMJM FAV EATR O

> [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit) : A BT**AU**JV BTA ALEJM AV EUMJM FAV EATR O

> [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) : A BTAUJV BTA AL**E**JM AV EUMJM FAV EATR O

> [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angstrom) : **A** BTAUJV BTA ALEJM AV EUMJM FAV EATR O

> [5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) : A BTAUJV BTA A**L**EJM AV EUMJM FAV EATR O

> [6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule) : A BTAUJV BTA ALE**JM** AV EUMJM FAV EATR O

> [7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farad) : A BTAUJV BTA ALEJM AV EUMJM **F**AV EATR O

> [8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0) : A BTAUJV BTA ALEJM AV EUMJM FAV EATR **O**

> [9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_core#AL_value) : A BTAUJV BTA **AL**EJM AV EUMJM FAV EATR O

> [10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere-turn) : A BTAUJV BTA ALEJM AV EUMJM FAV E**AT**R O

There are more symbols , but I am not sure what OP is looking for !

Comment: It's tagged [cipher], so I assumed that there is a decryption step before looking for constants/numbers, but I haven't got anywhere with it.

Comment: You may be right , I will "await" a reply from OP ! @fljx

Comment: Thanks for trying.